# Pandas dataframe .. resampling row by row

Tags: python, pandas

I have some intraday stockdata (e.g., DateTime, Open, Close) which I want to extend by aggregated meassures of the day.
Like:
Datetime, Open, Close, t_Open (day open), t_Close (day close).

When i use resample(), it resamples the entire day:

```
               DateTime     Open    Close   T_OPEN  T_CLOSE
165 2017-04-26 08:00:00  12485.6  12473.6  12485.6  12463.4
166 2017-04-26 08:15:00  12473.9  12473.9  12485.6  12463.4
167 2017-04-26 08:30:00  12473.6  12466.1  12485.6  12463.4
168 2017-04-26 08:45:00  12466.4  12469.6  12485.6  12463.4
169 2017-04-26 09:00:00  12470.1  12460.4  12485.6  12463.4
170 2017-04-26 09:15:00  12460.1  12460.1  12485.6  12463.4
171 2017-04-26 09:30:00  12459.9  12459.6  12485.6  12463.4
172 2017-04-26 09:45:00  12459.4  12463.4  12485.6  12463.4
173 2017-04-26 10:00:00  12462.9  12463.4  12485.6  12463.4
```

but i am looking for something, that resamples by row.
So that close is equal to t_close for every row, because it was the last obs at the givin point (and t_High will be the highest high UNTIL that row).

like this:

```
               DateTime     Open    Close   T_OPEN  T_CLOSE
165 2017-04-26 08:00:00  12485.6  12473.6  12485.6  12473.6
166 2017-04-26 08:15:00  12473.9  12473.9  12485.6  12473.9
167 2017-04-26 08:30:00  12473.6  12466.1  12485.6  12466.1
168 2017-04-26 08:45:00  12466.4  12469.6  12485.6  12469.6
```

Do you have an idea?

*UPDATE*
After the comments I have decided to create a more generic question :)
I need to calculate additional columns based on all data *until* the row i am working on. that means:

```
T_OPEN = is always equal to the "OPEN" value from the first Obs of that day
T_Close = is always the "CLOSE" value from the current line 
T_HIGH = is the highest "HIGH" value until that row of that day
T_LOW = is the lowest "LOW" value until that row of that day
```

I can solve this by iterating twice over that dataframe ... but i was looking/hoping for a more pandaslike option :)

Thanks and best wishes,
E.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you're trying to do. This should work:

```
df = df.loc[df['Open'] <= df['Close']]
df['T_CLOSE'] = df['Close']
```

Comment: If your solution is Ok, give me know, I woud like upvote it ;)

Comment: I think that's for the OP to decide... But I wouldn't mind an up vote anyway :)

Comment: Because my main problem is I dont understand question. So if accepted or give comment that solution is correct I upvote also.

Comment: sorry. i don't know what you want to do with the first line. the second works, although its a bit too simple. i would need something similar for Highs and Lows.. i will update my question with a more generic example! thanks @pshep123

Comment: @Ele, what is Obs?

Comment: Obs = Observation :)

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the issue by iterating and retaining values from higher/lower values

Thanks!
Elenio